# Get IP address of all NIC's without using external package

Tags: linux, sockets, python-2.7, ip-address, nic

I want to list ip address of all NICs connected to my machine (without using any external packages)

```
import socket
print socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2]
```

This code is working fine for Windows but on my Linux machine it outputs `127.0.1.1`

How do I change above code to make it work on Linux ?

---

The content of **/etc/hostname** is

```
machine-name
```

And the content of **/etc/hosts** is

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.1.1 machine-name 

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
fe00::0 ip6-localnet 
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix 
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes 
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: What value is `socket.gethostname()` (by itself) returning?

Comment: @MichaelSchuller socket.gethostname() returns my machine name

Comment: And what are the contents of `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` on that machine?

Comment: @MichaelSchuller **/etc/hostname** gives `machine-name` and **/etc/hosts** gives `127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 machine-name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters`

Comment: Most likely you really want to use [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces).

Comment: @HelmutGrohne i know how to implement this with netifaces but using it will add dependency to my code

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the content of **/etc/hosts**, which is what `socket` is using to match the hostname to the IP addresses.

If you change your **/etc/hosts** to the following, you should see both `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.1.1` on the list:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost machine-name
127.0.1.1 machine-name

# And of course your IPv6 settings below...
```

Any IP addresses which aren't in that file won't appear in the results of `socket.gethostbyname_ex()`.

Comment: but 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1 are not my machine IPs, my machine is connected to both ethernet network and wifi network

Comment: Yes, but you have to configure the machine so that it knows about those IPs. If those IPs aren't in `/etc/hosts`, then they are effectively invisible to the functions in the `socket` module.

Comment: but that configuration won't be generic as on changing wifi network ip will change

Comment: You may have to deal with that issue separately. [This link looks like it might be a good starting point for that.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122893/dynamically-change-etc-hosts)